# Hosting Open Source code with a restrictive license on GitHub

Tags: github

I want to know if it is allowed to host software on GitHub that is open sourced (in the sense that anyone can see the source) but with a license that does not allow redistribution (vanilla or modified), while still allowing users to do as they wish with the code without redistributing it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about terms and conditions related to GitHub.

Comment: Where would be the best place to ask this and I'll move it there. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, [Appropriate License for Available-Source, No-Unauthorized-Distribution](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/199643/69573) looks identical to your use case.

Comment: Ah that's brilliant. Thanks!if you pop that on as an answer I'll accept it. Tis exactly what I was after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely. You can use whatever license you want.